# How do I specify a boolean command line flag using Clap?

Tags: rust, clap

I want to add a command line flag. It's a flag, so it does not take an argument, it is either present or not. I also need to know how to read the flag, either TRUE or FALSE.

This is the code for defining the flag:

```
.arg(
    Arg::with_name("metal")
        .long("metal-micky")
        .required(false)
        .help("I want metal micky"),
)
```

I am trying to read the value like this:

```
let z = matches.value_of("metal");
```

However it is resulting in `None` when I print it:

```
println!("FLAG: {:?}", z);
```

It is `None` even when I specify the flag on the command line.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Don't know if this is the "approved" method but I use [`Args::takes_value`](https://docs.rs/clap/2.33.0/clap/struct.Arg.html#method.takes_value):

```rust
.arg(
    Arg::with_name("metal")
        .long("metal-micky")
        .required(false)
        .takes_value(false)
        .help("I want metal micky"),
)
```

Then check if the flag was passed with [`matches.is_present("metal")`](https://docs.rs/clap/2.33.0/clap/struct.ArgMatches.html#method.is_present)

Comment: In current Clap stable version this answer is outdated. Check out ciresh's one. To be short: replace `takes_value(false)` with `num_args(0)`.

Answer (score 26):

This can be done with the `action` attribute. If your field is a `bool` then by default the action selected is `ArgAction::SetTrue`.

This is quite nice since you don't need to set a value when you call the argument. It sets the value by default to true if used and false if not used when running the program.

```rust
use clap::Parser;

/// This is a simple program
#[derive(Parser, Debug)]
#[clap(author, version, about, long_about = None)]
struct Args {
   /// It just works!
   #[clap(long, short, action)]
   it_just_works: bool,
}

fn main() {
   let args = Args::parse();

    println!("It just works {}!", args.it_just_works)
}
```

To change the default behavior you can do this:

```
#[clap(long, short, action=ArgAction::SetFalse)]
```

[Docs](https://docs.rs/clap/latest/clap/_derive/_tutorial/index.html#argument-relations).

Answer (score 13):

The currently accepted answer is slightly outdated, you no longer have to specify `required(false)` when you specify `takes_value(false)`.  So, what you need is:

```
.arg(
    Arg::with_name("metal")
        .long("metal-micky")
        .takes_value(false)
        .help("I want metal mickey")
```

and check the presence with [`matches.is_present("metal")`](https://docs.rs/clap/2.33.0/clap/struct.ArgMatches.html#method.is_present).

Answer (score 13):

The builder based answers are both out of date. `with_name()` has been replace with `new()` in 3.0 and `takes_value()` has been replace with `num_args()` in 4.0. Also `is_present()` has been replace with `contains_id()` in 3.2. The new version would be:

```
.arg(
     Arg::new("metal")
        .long("metal-micky")
        .required(false)
        .num_args(0)
        .help("I want metal micky"),
)
```

Check if the flag was passed with [`contains_id()`](https://docs.rs/clap/latest/clap/struct.ArgMatches.html#method.contains_id)

Answer (score 1):

As of clap 4.4.11 use `clap::ArgAction::SetTrue`, you must also explicitly specify either a short or long version of the flag otherwise you will get this panicking error `` thread 'main' panicked at 'Argument 'metal` is positional and it must take a value but action is SetTrue' ``.

```
.arg(
    Arg::new("metal")
        .long("metal-micky")
        .short('m')
        .action(ArgAction::SetTrue)
        .help("I want metal micky"),
)
```

Note that `required` is implicitly set to `false`.

You get boolean value of the flag as so

```
let metal_micky_flag = matches.get_one::<bool>("metal").unwrap();
```